# Running ruby on rails scripts in Jenkinsfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-cli

Currently I set my Gitlab that whenever I push to a branch it will trigger a build in Jenkins using webhook. I'm using a plugin `Multibranch Pipeline` in Jenkins so that the build can run on all branches.

But I saw in Jenkins you need to put the scripts in **Jenkinsfile**, but I cannot find a good reference on how to run ruby scripts this configuration.

These are the tasks that I need to achieve

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
cp config/database-gitlab.yml config/database.yml
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake test
```

How can I put this scripts in the Jenkinsfile

```
node {
  try {
    stage ('Clone') {
      checkout scm
    }
    stage ('Build') {
      sh "echo 'shell scripts to build project...'"
      sh "echo 'Running ${env.BRANCH_NAME}'"
    }
    stage ('Tests') {
    }
  } catch (err) {
    currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
      throw err
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put all your scripts in a ruby file and run something like this:

```
sh 'ruby ./script.rb'
```

Answer (score 0):

A script example of what @SatyamSingh is describing would be like this:

install.sh

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
cp config/database-gitlab.yml config/database.yml
bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
bundle exec rake test
```

Jenkinsfile

```
node {
...
    stage ('Clone') {
      checkout scm
    }
    stage ('Build') {
        sh gem install bundler
        sh bundle install
        sh cp config/database-gitlab.yml config/database.yml
        sh bundle exec rake db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
        sh bundle exec rake test
        ....
    }
    stage ('Tests') {
...
    }
...
}
```

Both of the above should be part of your projects SCM repository. The Jenkinsfile executes each of your shell commands as steps inside the 'Build' stage.